# Bitaps.com Error Code 10

Tags: php, bitcoin

This is the exact code they give me in the Query examples with the fields i added. No matter what I cannot get it to work. There other examples work but not the 1 i need.

The error I get: {"error_code": 10, "message": "payment_list element incorrect keys", "details": ""}

However it works when I use their onsite execute program.

```
<?php
  function post_api($url, $postfields) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    return $result;
  }

  $confirmations = 3;
  $callback = urlencode("https://website.ml/ipnbtc?id=2&email=email@gmail.com");
  $fee = "low";
  $rules = [
    array('address'=>'btc1', 'qouta'=> 95),
    array('address'=>'btc2', 'qouta'=> 5),
    array('address'=>'btc2', 'qouta'=> 0)
  ];

  $postfields = json_encode(array('type'=>"payment_distribution", 'payment_distribution'=> $rules ));
  $data = post_api("https://bitaps.com/api/create/payment/smartcontract/". $callback . "?confirmations=" . $confirmations . "&fee_level=" . $fee, $postfields);
  echo $data;
  $respond = json_decode($data,true);
  $address = $respond["address"]; // Bitcoin address to receive payments
  $payment_code = $respond["payment_code"]; //Payment Code
  $invoice = $respond["invoice"]; // Invoice to view payments and transactions
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mistake in word **qouta**. Need **quota**

```
$rules = [
    array('address'=>'btc1', 'quota'=> 95),
    array('address'=>'btc2', 'quota'=> 5),
    array('address'=>'btc2', 'quota'=> 0)
  ];
```